# SqlDataSource pass variable

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to pass a variable to a SelectCommand in SqlDataSource.  I have this MyIdVal that need to be passed.

Here is the code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
<%=MyIdVal%>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="myIdDataSource">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="myIdDataSource" 
    ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection  %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = @MyIdVal" >   

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
```

The code works fine if I hardcode the id, so how this works?

Comment: try SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = <%= MyIdVal%>"

Comment: it gives me this error now Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<%=MyIdVal %>' to data type int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two ways to do it.

1. Bind the Parameter value to a control

   ```
   <selectparameters>
       <asp:controlparameter 
               name="MyIdVal" 
               controlid="DropDownListBooks" 
               propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
   </selectparameters>
   ```

2 . Use the [SqlDataSource.Selecting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx)

```
protected void myIdDataSource_Selecting
    (object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["MyIdVale"] = MyIdVal;
}
```